# Pyinstaller Application Error on Embedded OS

Tags: python-3.x, windows, exe, pyinstaller, windows-xp-embedded

[image: Exe error]

I am trying to build an executable to run on Windows XP Embedded.  The app itself is a GUI application built with python 3.4.3 and PyQT4-4.11.4. I use pyinstaller to build the exe with the command below :

```
pyinstaller --clean --windowed --onefile install_wizard.py --icon="images\installer.ico" --name "Installer"
```

I can build and run the exe on with no issues on a Virtualbox running either XP or XP embedded.

I also have a flash disk with a Windows XP Embedded image, I am able to build the executable, but I get an application error when I try to run it.

Any ideas, I've looked through the Pyinstaller docs and haven't seen anything that would give me a clue.

---

**Looks like it might have something to do wih pyinstaller, I did a simple test using py2exe instead, and that seem to work.**

But any info on why XPe does not agree with pyinstaller would be great.

Comment: Is it your application that is crashing or Pyinstaller?  If not the latter I don't understand why you might think the Pyinstaller docs might help - this being an error in _your_ applications run-time.  Does the Python script run directly without packaging with Pyinstaller - i.e. if you manually place the script and its dependencies on your target?

Comment: @Clifford  I narrowed it down to the pyinstaller, I bundled a simple file using py2exe and it work, and yes manually placing the scripts on the machine and running them works.